# Copy files from Google Compute Engine instance to Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to copy files from a Google Compute Engine instance directly to a Google Cloud Storage bucket?  There doesn't seem to be any info on the [`gcloud compute copy-files`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/copy-files) help page or in the Google Cloud Storage documentation.

The only examples I am seeing are to download it locally and then upload it again, which doesn't make sense for me if there are very big files.

Answer (score 10):

The best way to do this is to SSH into the instance and use the `gsutil` command to copy files directly from the GCE instance to a GCS bucket.

Keep in mind the instance needs to have Google Cloud Storage "write scope" which is a setting you need to create when you first create the instance OR you can add later using a service account.

If you're using a machine image that was provided by Google, `gsutil` is already installed on the VM instance.

Example:

```
gsutil cp file1 file2 gs://bucket
```

If you have a lot of files to upload, you can parallelize via `-m`:

```
gsutil -m cp file1 file2 gs://bucket
```

If you want to recursively upload a directory, use `-r`:

```
gsutil cp -r dir1 gs://bucket
```

See the docs for [`gsutil cp`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) for more information.